# Groovy enum - how to return map of enum?

Tags: java, groovy, enums

I have a groovy enum that includes a method to return the values of the enum as a map, with some additional logic in it.

Here is an example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    CAT('feline', 'meow'),
    DOG('canine', 'woof')

    MyEnum(String animalType, String sound){
          this.animalType = animalType
          this.sound = sound
    }

    private final String animalType
    private final String getAnimalType(){
        animalType
    }

    private final String sound
    private final String getSound(){
        sound
    }

    def getMap(List animalsToReturn){
        Map result = [:]

        // do some stuff...
        for (animal in animalsToReturn){
            result.put(MyEnum.animal.animalType, MyEnum.animal.sound)
        }

        return result
    }

}


myMap = MyEnum.getMap(['DOG'])
```

Whenever I call MyEnum.getMap, I get errors saying that method signatures don't match. Even if I make getMap have an empty signature and hardcode values in the method as a test. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `static` method.

```
static Map getMap(List animalsToReturn) {
    Map result = [:]

    // do some stuff...
    for (animal in animalsToReturn){
        MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum[animal]
        result.put(myEnum.animalType, myEnum.sound)
    }
    result
}
```

Above should work, however, there is a simpler way to achieve the same result in Groovy.

```
static Map getMap(List animalsToReturn) {   
    animalsToReturn
        .collect { MyEnum.valueOf it }
        .collectEntries { [ it.animalType, it.sound ] }
}
```

or just

```
animalsToReturn.collectEntries {
    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum[it] 
    [ myEnum.animalType, myEnum.sound ] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why I keep forgetting groovy is built on java!

Answer (score 2):

The getMap method should be static.

Also as you are using String in the animalsToReturn list. I think it will be safer to not use "valueof" or MyEnum['DOG'].

Try this:

```
static getMap(List animalsToReturn) {

  MyEnum.values().findAll {
    animalsToReturn.contains(it.toString())
  }.collectEntries {
    [(it.animalType): it.sound]
  }
}
```